# Easiest way to style selected element

Tags: jquery, css

Good Day

I want to know if it is possible to style a **selected** **li** element the same way you style it when you hover over it? Or do you have to use Javascript to assign an 'active' class to the selected item and style it like that?

HTML

```
<div id="areas" class="span2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#pretoriaDetail">Pretoria</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#potchDetail">Potch</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#jhbDetail">JHB</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="span12">
    <div class="hidden" id="pretoriaDetail">Pretoria Content</div>
    <div class="hidden" id="potchDetail">Potch Content</div>
    <div class="hidden" id="jhbDetail">JHB Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#areas {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;

}
#areas ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#areas ul li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #073640;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 20% 10%;
    /*to vertically center text inside the ul*/
    text-align: center;
}
#areas ul li:hover {
    background: #610052;
}
#areas ul li a {
    font-family:'Open Sans', 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#areasMap {
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f4a8/5/)

If you look at my fiddle, the hover class works fine, but I want to keep the element that purple color when you actually select it - can i use plain CSS or do I have to use JS?

thanks

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, you are looking to style the FOCUSED element and not a SELECTED element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to style a focussed anchor in .css ?

```
a:focus {your styling}
```

Like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f4a8/9/) :

```
#areas ul li a:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: ComputerArts's answer below will be more usefull, however, you answer my question - Is there a css solution? Yes there is, but only on anchor tags. Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to add a class (for example .active) when you click on it. It will be recognized throughout all the browsers

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f4a8/8/)

JS

```
 $(function () {
     $("#areas ul a").click(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $("#areas ul li").removeClass('active'); //clears the active class for elements
         $(this).parent().addClass('active'); //adds the class to clicked li
         $(".hidden").hide(500);
         $($(this).attr("href")).show(500)
     });

 });
```

CSS

```
#areas ul li:hover,
#areas ul li.active {
    background: #610052;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ComputerArts. Good answer, and I wll be using it since I am working with li elements, but I think the answer above was more relevant to my 'easiest and css preferably' specific question...I will be using your code anyways, appreciate